# IE8 doesn't accept a valid certificate while Firefox does

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, godaddy, internet-explorer-8

When I browse my site with IE8, it gives the error below.

`"The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority."`

But when I use Firefox, it says it's verified by GoDaddy.com, Inc.

I installed `gd-class2-root.cer` to IE8 but the problem persists. Do you have any ideas for that?

Thanks!

Comment: I've heard that GoDaddy certs have had issues in IE8, but I can't find reference to that right now....   I seem to remember having to get GoDaddy support on the phone, something invalid in the validation path or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded all certificates from [Go Daddy Repository](https://certs.godaddy.com/anonymous/repository.seam) and installed `gd_bundle.crt`, now it it seems ok.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html to make sure that the server is giving out all the correct Intermediate certificates. There are usually 3 of them with GoDaddy.

Comment: I checked it and it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

The directions for GoDaddy certificates indicates that you should disable the "Starfield Class 2 Certificate Authority" certificate.  Ran into the same problem recently.  Had to enable (now runs with no problem).

Load an MMC console with "Certificates" snap in for the local computer & Computer Account. The go to Intermediate Certification Authorities.  From there, go to the Certificates folder.  Right click on the "Starfield Class 2 Certificate Authority" cert.  You should see the "Disable all purposes for this certificate" selected... choose the top option "Enable all purposes for this certificate".

Comment: I checked but there is no such certificate exists there. I'm using Windows 7, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This could help!

After bying a certificate at Go Daddy, i installed it on my apache unix server.

The certificate installation was ok everywhere, firefox, Chrome, IE9, Opera, Iphone, IPad, Android.

Except on IE8 and in the Go Daddy test tools, where a get an error message.

I solved this problem, simply (after hours!) by changing the next parameters in my apache configuration file.

SSLCertificateFile 
SSLCertificateKeyFile 
SSLCertificateChainFile

In the default SSL virtual Host section.

I understand that some browser like IE8, QtWeb, when reaching a https web site ask then the certificate whitout the new HTTP host parameter. Then they get the values of the default virtualHost .

Regards
Gilbert